# "No executable" when using dotnet add

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm trying to add a Nuget .core package using

```
dotnet add package [package name]
```

but get "No executable found matching command dotnet-add".  I've installed Nuget and can use "dotnet" to create applications, restore, build, run, etc.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: what does `dotnet --version` return? you need at least 1.0.0 (no 1.0.0-preview)

Comment: Yep, I was running preview.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `dotnet add` family of verbs was released in version `1.0.0` of the dotnet cli tooling and is not part of the `1.0.0-preview2-*` range of versions previously used for `project.json` projects.

This means that `dotnet add` verbs are only available for msbuild based projects (=> `.csproj`).